# NS3 Mobility models in WSN

Tags: c++, iot, wireless, ns-3, auv3

In ns-3, how can I move a node to specific points using `mobilitymodel`. I want to make a list, containing pre-defined positions/points, and move node to every point, and pause at every point, for example 1 second. Furthermore, I don't know how to make the node move to those points.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to check the examples under `/src/mobility/examples/`. Then, try `ns2-mobility-trace.cc` file for understanding, which uses a pre-defined node trajectory, which is generated with `ns2`. Then. you can use tools, such as `bonnmotion`, `SUMO`, or `ns-2 setdest utility`, to create a mobility file of your choice with pre-defined positions/trajectory of the device. Then, you can easily integrate your mobility files, see another example here [mobility examples](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/mobility.html).